# What Ethical and Legal Provisions Release One from "Mandatory Reporting"?

Tags: social-psychology, clinical-psychology, ideation, confidence, ethics

## Question

What provisions exist that can be applied to provide assurance to a client or patient that they can talk, "off the record", "without repercussions", and that nothing will be documented?

## Context

A client is experiencing considerable difficulties navigating the distinctions between ideation and intent, (thoughts regarding suicide, retaliation, harming others, etc).

However, they feel they cannot be open about these issues, because of the extremity of the reactions that are possible, (hospitalization, etc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best asked in Law.SE

Answer (score 0):

You would need to seek the professional advice of someone in the legal profession for this but as far as I am aware there are no provisions releasing anyone from legal duties under mandatory reporting requirements.